# Why is it safe to assume $M$ is less than all $N$s in Håstad's Broadcast Attack

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am reading the Wikipedia article on [Broadcast attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_Attack#H.C3.A5stad.27s_Broadcast_Attack). In the proof, the editor made an assumption that $M$ is less than all $N$. Why is this assumption safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RSA doesn't work at all if the message is larger than the modulus.

In practical confidentiality applications, the message typically just consists of a symmetric session key and some identifying metadata, so there's plenty of room for it (*plus* some randomized padding to defend against the attack) within the key sizes that are needed for security anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The Broadcast Attack is an attack on the RSA cryptosystem. The [Wikipedia page on RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) has the following:

> Alice transmits her public key (n, e) to Bob and keeps the private key secret. Bob then wishes to send message M to Alice.
>   He first turns M into an integer m, such that 0 ≤ m < n ...

So it looks like that's just the standard protocol? For a more in-depth answer about why, I would have to substantially refresh my understanding of how RSA works.